SwiftUI layout depends unexpectedly on Metal texture2DDescriptor
I have a SwiftUI view that should display two views in an HStack with equal width.
My ContentView is:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Group {
                View1()
                View1()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .border(.black)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}

This gives the correct layout:

However, my app has to use a more complex view as 2nd view. View2 is initialized with a Metal texture that is converted to a CGImage, and the body uses an Image initialized with this CGImage:
struct View2: View {
    
    let texture: MTLTexture
    
    init() {
        let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
        let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat.rgba8Unorm, 
                                                                         width:  Int(700), 
                                                                         height: Int(100), 
                                                                         mipmapped: false)
        texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)!    
    }
    
    func textureToCGImage(texture: MTLTexture) -> CGImage? {
        let width  = texture.width
        let height = texture.height
        let rowBytes = width * 4
        let length = rowBytes * height
        
        var bgraBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
        let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height)
        texture.getBytes(&bgraBytes, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)
        
        guard let providerRef = CGDataProvider(data: NSData(bytes: &bgraBytes, length: length)) else { return nil }
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        
        return CGImage(width: width, height: height,
                       bitsPerComponent: 8, bitsPerPixel: 32, bytesPerRow: rowBytes,
                       space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                       provider: providerRef, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: false,
                       intent: .defaultIntent)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let image = textureToCGImage(texture: texture)!
        VStack {
            Image(image, scale: 1, orientation: .up, label: Text("View2"))
                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
            Text("View2")
        }
    }
}

With a View2 as 2nd image, the layout looks as follows:

I don't know why the SwiftUI layout system depends on the width of the MTLTextureDescriptor.
Is it possible to render both views with the same width, independent of the device size?

Why did you expect otherwise? Images have a fixed size unless you put .resizable().

@Sweeper This was the problem. I am sorry for the maybe silly question, but I am not so experienced in SwiftUI. Maybe you can make your comment to an answer, so that I can close the question?
